# Display the value of a field in a form with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, shopify-app

I am able to display a form in a modal window doing this:

**index.html.erb**

```
 <a href="#" onclick="newModal('<%= form_edit_url %>','Title')">Edit</a>
```

And it works.

Now I want to make an edit link. It will display the same form with the fields that were previously filled.

I send params to the controller with:

```
            <li><%= link_to 'edit', edit_path(address.attributes) %></li>
```

But it doesn't display the form in a modal window...

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try something like `<%= link_to 'Edit', '#', onclick: "newModal('#{edit_path(address.attributes)}', 'Title')" %>`?

Comment: Thank you so much, It works! @SebastianPalma

Comment: Take a look to David's answer, that might help you to simplify your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might better to have you modal content as a partial that you render in the modal. 
`$("#shared-modal").html("<%= render('new_modal', locals: {zone: @zone})) %>";`

To have your fields fill out again you would need to write some JS in the modal that will find those values and duplicate them into your new form fields.